# openssl installation for key hash purposes

Tags: android, facebook, openssl

im doing a tutorial on facebook intergration with android app and it needs a haskey for it to work and generating a key hash requires to install an openssl in download one already in this link https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q= but im not sure how to install it when i click on the openssl application it prompts a command line how do i install openssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate Key hash using this code also...

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/KeyText"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
               PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.key", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
               for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());

                      TextView tvmyName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.KeyText);
                      tvmyName.setText(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));


               }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: U have to create Base64 class also

Comment: i need to copy it and paste it on my folder?

Comment: yes, in src folder create new class named as Base64.java and copy the stuff

Comment: i save the file base64coder.java in biz/source_code/base64coder/base64coder.java but same error

Comment: What is this "biz" here?

Comment: name of folder where i put the base64coder in a series of folder from scr\biz\source_code_base64coder then inside it the file

Comment: the method encodeBytes(bytes[]) is undefined for the type base64

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412778/upload-image-from-android-phone-to-the-server
try the solution of above link...

Comment: will the hashkey be generated in the textview?or logcat?\

Comment: last please check this paste bin ive done this and still no haskey generated http://pastebin.com/gKE3GngQ if no result then il work out his myself